# Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String.Index'

Tags: swift

Cannot subscript a value of type `String` with an index of type `String.Index`

```
if let x = formulars.firstIndex(of: "("){
                formulars[x] = ""
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`String` is a `Collection` but not a `MutableCollection`, which means that the subscript is *read-only.* Also subscripting can not be used to *remove* a collection element.

To remove the character at the found position, use

```
if let idx = formulars.firstIndex(of: "(") {
    formulars.remove(at: idx)
}
```

And to replace the first occurrence of "(" with a different string use

```
if let range = formulars.range(of: "(") {
    formulars.replaceSubrange(range, with: "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `replacingOccurrences`

```
formulars = formulars.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
```

Comment: Just note that this removes *all* occurrences of "(", not just the first (which may or may not be wanted).